# e.Keycode not act as expected

Tags: .net, visual-studio, keypress, keycode

( sorry if title not clear enough )

in visual studio 2013 i wrote below code in ComdoBox key up

combobox data source set to odbc data table

I'm trying to make combobox act with Autocomplete text from it's items.

```
Dim PrK As Boolean = e.KeyCode = Keys.Back Or Keys.End Or Keys.Home _
                     Or Keys.PageDown Or Keys.PageUp Or Keys.Delete Or Keys.Up Or Keys.Down _
                     Or Keys.Right Or Keys.Left
If PrK = True Then
    Exit Sub
End If
Dim index As Integer
Dim Oldtext = cmbSubProName.Text
index = cmbSubProName.FindString(Oldtext)
If index > -1 Then
    Dim res As String
    res = cmbSubProName.Items(index).ToString
    cmbSubProName.SelectedIndex = index
    cmbSubProName.SelectionStart = Oldtext.Length
    cmbSubProName.SelectionLength = cmbSubProName.Text.Length
End If
```

when run project and press any key ( v, y or any other characters ) inside combo box I find Prk usually true !!

i also tried below code and the same

```
if e.KeyCode = Keys.Back Or Keys.End Or Keys.Home _
                     Or Keys.PageDown Or Keys.PageUp Or Keys.Delete Or Keys.Up Or Keys.Down _
                     Or Keys.Right Or Keys.Left then
exit sub
end if
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general rule, `True` is considered to be any non-zero value, and `False` is zero.

Your value for `Prk` is set incorrectly - you've got confused on your syntax. What you really want is this:

```
Dim PrK As Boolean = e.KeyCode = Keys.Back Or _
                     e.KeyCode = Keys.End Or _
                     e.KeyCode = Keys.Home Or _
                     e.KeyCode = Keys.PageDown Or _
                     e.KeyCode = Keys.PageUp Or _
                     e.KeyCode = Keys.Delete Or _
                     e.KeyCode = Keys.Up Or _
                     e.KeyCode = Keys.Down Or _
                     e.KeyCode = Keys.Right Or _
                     e.KeyCode = Keys.Left
```

The syntax as you've written it is actually doing a binary-`Or` of the values of all those key enumerations, which is always going to be a non-zero value.